# How to test Unicode "non-chars" (lsep, rsep etc.)?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, generator

Is there an application or a utility for generating non-characters, such as U-2028 and U-2029 (line separators)?

Comment: Sure: Type `&#x2028;` into your website, and your browser will generate the appropriate character.

Comment: Those are not non-characters.  They do not have that property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred method is to type into a browser address bar eg:

```
javascript:'A\u2028B\u2029C'
```

and then copy and paste them from the page.

If you really need to enter such characters a lot, you could potentially use [MSKLC](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=22339) to create a keyboard layout that can type them directly. For example on my own keyboard layout I've got non-breaking-space, zero-width-space and half-space on shift and alt combinations with the space bar.

Note that browser support for displaying replacement glyphs for these particular characters may vary, so if you don't see them, try another browser. They are visible for me in Chrome (52.0.2743.116).

Answer (score -2):

If you are with Windows, you don't need external tools: press alt, and + sign, and the hex code.

If you need `\u2028`, you press `Alt` and `+`, and `2028`, the sign appears.

It depends on the code page you are using. Please refer to

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code

and

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page

In my case, with my code page, I have `ý` when typing alt code 2028.

Comment: Irrelevant? Try to comment before downvoting.